Getting HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error, ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 module ManagedPipelineHandler
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler"
Detailed Error Information:
Module   ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification   ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler   ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code   0x800703e9
I am running IIS 10 on Windows Server 2022. And I have already tried below without any success:

Re-install ,Net Extensibility using dism
Tried Re-Installing .Net481 using offline installer, and installing IIS-Net45 using dism
Verify the permissions for the DLL.
Created a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. But it has no relevant message
But, still I get the error

I have this in the web.config
<handlers>
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
   <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
   <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="" />
</handlers>


Please check your configuration carefully, you may find that you have not assigned a value to the preCondition property. It should be something like: preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"
Just refer to this doc for more values of this property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/settings-schema/ms690693(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#attributes
